# Stamping User ID in Formula Field and Populating a Lookup

Tags: formula, lookup

I'm looking to create a formula field that stamps the running user's ID on the Campaign Member Object when a status is set to "MD Approved". Once that UserID is populated on the Campaign Member record, how can I get a user lookup set to link to that user on the same record?

THank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need formula. Formula will be evaluated each time even the record is not edited. You can directly fill lookup field on Campaign Member. [`$User`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm) global variable can be used to get current user ID.

> **$USER**
>  A global merge field type to use when referencing information about the current user. User merge fields can reference
>   information about the user such as alias, title, and ID. Most of the
>   fields available on the User standard object are also available on
>   $User.

You can write a workflow rule having criteria as:

```
      AND (
             ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'MD Approved'),
             ISCHANGED(Status__c)
          )
```

Update lookup field directly. Field update would as below:

```
$User.ID
```